# How to run application and change settings in it using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to run the installation(which is a single step procedure) of one of the tool(exe file) then in that tool,select File -> Settings and do some settings(select one option(which is a Radio button) and deselect the other selected one).

Is this type of operation is possible by writing the batch file?

Or any other options except writing batch file is available where I can do this operation?

Please provide some useful links..

Answer (score 1):

You did not say specifically what the exe is or where that program stores it's settings, so unless there is a way to provide a transform file for the installer for the mystery exe, your best bet is to figure out where the settings for that program are saved (in a .ini file in a folder somewhere, in a reg key, etc), then use a line in the batch file to copy a preconfigured ini/settings file to where it needs to go, or to run in a .reg file to import the setting you want.